# Reuse background definition between two feature files in Specflow

Tags: c#, testing, visual-studio-2012, specflow

I have several specflow .feature files to test different entities of a web api project.

For every entity I have to create a background with all the needed data in my database, but before of all I need to delete all data, and need to delete using web api calls (not by sql query). I'm doing this:

```
Background: 
Given I make a new request to localhost on port 53364 
    And the path is api/voipport/deleteAll 
    And the request type is Delete
    When the request has completed
Given I make a new request to localhost on port 53364 
    And the path is api/loopblockingexception/deleteAll 
    And the request type is Delete
    When the request has completed
Given I make a new request to localhost on port 53364 
    And the path is api/stimulationcode/deleteAll 
    And the request type is Delete
    When the request has completed
Given I make a new request to localhost on port 53364 
    And the path is api/switch/deleteAllMtp3
    And the request type is Delete
    When the request has completed
Given I make a new request to localhost on port 53364 
    And the path is api/enviroment/deleteAll 
    And the request type is Delete
    When the request has completed

Given it has the following topologies
    | Id | Name  | Description  |
    | 1  | Test  | Description  |
    | 2  | Test2 | Descritpion2 |
Given it has the following eas
    | Id | TopologyId | Name  | Description  | SipListenIPAddress | SipListenPort | SipTelephonyCapacity |
    | 1  | 1          | Test  | Description1 | 127.0.0.1          | 8080          | 5                    |
Given it has the following networks
    | Id | TopologyId | NetworkTypeId | Name  | CliPrivacyRespected |
    | 1  | 1          | 2             | Test1 | Description1        |
    | 2  | 1          | 1             | Test2 | Description2        |
Given it has the following switchs
    | Id | NetworkId | SwitchType | Name          | Description              |
    | 1  | 1         | 2          | Ss7SwitchTest | Ss7SwitchTestDescription |
    | 2  | 1         | 1          | SipSwitchTest | SipSwitchTestDescription |
Given it has the following mtp3Switchs
    | Id | Name            | Description                | SignallingHost | SignallingLinkCode | SwitchId | EasId |
    | 1  | SwitchMtp3Test  | SwitchMtp3DescriptionTest  | 192.168.1.1    | 13245              | 1        | 1     |
    | 2  | SwitchMtp3Test2 | SwitchMtp3DescriptionTest2 | 192.168.1.2    | 13246              | 1        | 1     |
```

It works perfect, but I have several .feature files that need to execute the same deleteAll methods. Can I write any kind of method with all the Given/When instructions in other .feature file (or another kind of file) and call this method from every background code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont forget that your `[Binding]`s are global. In theory you could have one binding file with all your `Given` \ `When` \ `Then`s in it.

Also, why don't you send your WebService a single reset command, rather than building them up in this manner? You could enable a new command such as `api/testing/deleteAll` which is only availble if you run your webService with a special config value.