# Reusing SpecFlow backgrounds, is this right?

Tags: bdd, specflow

I have a little over a month working with SpecFlow and got to a point where I configured a [Background Scenario](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Using-Gherkin-Language-in-SpecFlow/) to setup/verify common data on a database, so the next step was trying to reuse the background for several feature files, to avoid cutting and pasting.

It has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859606/reuse-background-definition-between-two-feature-files-in-specflow) but I expected something else, more user-friendly, just as the Background scenario is easy to understand and update:

```
Background:
Given I have created the following currencies:
| Code | Name                 |
| USD  | United States Dollar |
| EUR  | Euro                 |

And I have created the following countries:
| Code | Currency | Name          |
| US   | USD      | United States |
| ES   | EUR      | Spain         |
| IT   | EUR      | Italy         |
```

I found a quite naive solution that is working (or at least seems to, so far), but I'm concerned it may lead me the wrong way, because of my shallow knowledge of SpecFlow.

Taking a look at the generated code for a feature file I got to this:

1. Create a "feature" file that only has the background scenario, named something like "CommonDataSetup"
2. Create a step definition like:

   ```
   [Given(@"common data configuration has been verified")]
   public void GiveCommonDataConfigurationHasBeenVerified()
   {
       // this class is inside the generated feature file
       var commonSetup = new CommonDataSetupFeature();
       var scenarioInfo = new ScenarioInfo("Common data configuration", ((string[])(null)));

       commonSetup.FeatureSetup();
       commonSetup.ScenarioSetup(scenarioInfo);

       commonSetup.FeatureBackground();

       commonSetup.ScenarioCleanup();
       commonSetup.FeatureTearDown();
   }
   ```
3. In the Background of the other feature files write:

   ```
   Background:
   Given common data configuration has been verified
   ```

So now I can reuse the "common data configuration" step definition in as many feature files I need keeping DRY, and background scenarios can be much shorter.

I seems to work fine, But I wonder, is this a the right way to achieve background reuse?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a conversation with a business person who wants the feature, they probably don't say "Given common data configuration has been verified..."

They probably say something like, "Okay, you've got your standard currencies and country codes..."

Within that domain, as long the idea of standard countries and currencies is really well-known and understood, you don't need to include it. It has to be the case that *every single person on the team* is familiar with these, though. The whole business needs to be familiar with them. If they're that completely, totally familiar, then re-introducing a table full of them at the beginning of every scenario would be waste.

Anything you can do to eliminate that waste and get to the interesting bits of the scenario is good. Remember that the purpose of the conversations is to surface uncertainty and misunderstandings, and nobody's likely to get these wrong. The automation is a record of those conversations, and you really don't even need to have much of a conversation for this step.

Do have the conversations, though. Even if it's just one line and everyone knows what it is, using the business language for it is important. Without that, you'll end up discussing these really boring bits to try and work out what you each mean by "common data configuration" and "verify" before you can move on to the interesting parts of the scenarios.

Short version: I'd expect to see something like:

```
Given standard currencies and country codes
When...
```

You don't even need to use background for that, and however you implement it is fine. If you have a similar situation with standard data that's slightly less familiar, then include it in each feature file; it's important not to hide magic. Remember that readability trumps DRY in tests (which are really records of conversations).

Comment: Thanks Lunivore. Reading your answer and @Andreas Willich's I got to understand what's happening me. I started with BBD as a way to do back-end integration testing and explain front-end developers how to use the back-end services. So... my "users" were developers and I liked "background" and step's table input as a great tool to seed the database, so "obviously" I "had" to reuse the background. However looking at it from the user's point of view, these are TACIT givens, so they don't think about them and are, actually, noise. So I'll go the way Andreas suggests, with a twist I'll post here.

Comment: Miguel, it's fine to put these in as background too. Don't hide them, though, or one day Spain will leave the Euro, someone will update the data and it will take you three days to work out why 180 of your scenarios are suddenly failing, at a time when you really, really need them as a safety net.

Answer (score 1):

I understand where the need comes, but reusing the same background in different feature files is against the idea behind Gherkin.

See https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin

> Gherkin is the language that Cucumber understands. It is a Business Readable, Domain Specific Language that lets you describe software’s behaviour without detailing how that behaviour is implemented.

With the "Given common data configuration has been verified" step it is not more business readable.

Additional your current implementation messes with the internal state of SpecFlow. It is now somehow working, but when you will get in trouble with it.

If you need something setup in every test, did you had a look at the various Hooks? 
http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Hooks/

With an [BeforeScenario]- hook you could setup your tests.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, thanks for the link, I understand your point, this could qualify as a "complex state", but it's very convenient for setting up data in the database for integration and acceptance tests. I've been using hooks to setup context like database structure, application's DI container and SpecFlow's container to pass data between steps, and I understand I can "hardcode" table parameters when calling a step from another, but you need code to update them and can't be delegated to a user or analyst. Could this lead to a new feature for SpecFlow?

Comment: I will talk with some people about it. Let's see, if this is possible to do.

Comment: Thanks, Andreas, I think I got to "really" understand your point, reading also @Lunivore's answer. Actually most of that "background" only needs to be run when creating the database (using EF's migrations I just delete the DB when I need a fresh start), so a BeforeTestRun hook would be enough. However I want to take advantage of the background secuence and step's table input, and I'll be looking for a way to execute an "independent" test scenario from the hook, so any help will be much appreciated.